# How to block only the x-y zoom of oxyplot library graph?

Tags: .net, wpf, graph, oxyplot

I am working on oxyplot and i have succesfully drawn a graph. Oxyplot provides a good facility to zoom only in x-axis when scrolled over x-axis and zoom only over y-axis when scrolled over y-axis and 
the third one is when we scroll over the plot then it zooms in both X-Y plane.

I know to block zoom on Xaxis by doing this :

```
 var dateAxis = new DateTimeAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom, "Temps", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, IntervalLength = 80 };
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(dateAxis);
        var valueAxis = new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, 0) { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, Title = "Voltage(mV)" };
        dateAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;           
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(valueAxis);
```

I also know to zoom on y-Axis by doing this:

```
  var dateAxis = new DateTimeAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom, "Temps", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, IntervalLength = 80 };
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(dateAxis);
        var valueAxis = new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, 0) { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, Title = "Voltage(mV)" };
        valueAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;           
        PlotModel.Axes.Add(valueAxis);
```

But dont't know to block zoom only when it is scrolled over plotted graph(both X-Y),I just want to block the both X-Y plane zoom. Please take care that it must zoom in x-Axis when srolled on x-axis 
and it must also zoom when scrolled on y_axis But it must not zoom when scrolled over X-Y plane plot of the graph.

Comment: I've tried overriding the method `PlotModel.ZoomAllAxes(double factor)` to block it, but it is not `virtual` and cannot be overriden. Maybe you can ask the creator here to change it or give you another solution: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues